# Description is grayed out in Layer List -- ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

I am trying to add layer descriptions for a GIS application in ArcGIS Online.

However, when I try to add a description, the option is grayed out in the legend drop-down menu.

Is there a way to enable the descriptions?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot? Are other options greyed out or just description? Is it for all layers or just one (or a few)?